# Kotlin: What can I do when a Java library has an overload of both primitive and boxed type?

Tags: kotlin, overloading

For example, FastUtil's `IntArrayList` has a `push` method that accepts both `int` (primitive) and `Integer` (boxed), but Kotlin sees these both as the same function `push(Int)`, therefore I cannot use the function at all as the function is ambiguous.

What should I do when a Java library has overloads for both the primitive and boxed type?

(p.s. I am aware that I can use the `add(int)` method. I am in search of what to do if I come across such a problem in the future.)

Answer (score 10):

Consider these methods in Java:

```
void f(int x) { }
void f(Integer y) { }
```

In Kotlin, they are seen as

```
f(x: Int)
f(x: Int!)
```

<sup>The second method has a parameter of [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types), meaning it *might be* nullable, corresponding to `Integer`.</sup>

First one can be simply called with Kotlin `Int` passed:

```
f(5) // calls f(int x)
```

To call the second one, you can cast the argument to nullable `Int?`, thus selecting the overload:

```
f(5 as Int?) // calls f(Integer y)
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working with Kotlin 1.0.2 stable (`x` is an `Int`): http://i.imgur.com/KLVy5Vn.png

Comment: @Jire, ah, indeed. I had tested it only with Java sources within the the same project, and it had worked for that case. The problem is that for `push(Integer)` the Kotlin signature is `push(Int)` for some reason and not `push(Int!)`.

Comment: @Jire, this turned out to be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: This solution doesn't work as of `v1.0.3` but apparently does work on `v1.1-M01`

Comment: @hotkey Even in v1.1-M01 you can't call the primitive version if you want to use an argument

Comment: @Jire, agreed, but [the related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/KT-11440) has been marked as fixed and has target version 1.0.4, so the fix will hopefully be released soon.

Comment: This problem is referenced in [Effective Java Item #41](https://github.com/mgp/book-notes/blob/master/effective-java-2nd-edition.markdown#item-41-use-overloading-judiciously). The author recommends just this: either cast your argument to the boxed type (e.g. `5 as Int?`) or use some other means to force your argument into the boxed type (e.g. invoke `Integer.valueOf(5)`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing a Java class to serve as an intermediary?  That is, write your own java class with the method you want Kotlin to see, then call that method from your Kotlin code.

Comment: That is a viable solution but don't you suspect there be an easier way?