# Why is Integer parameter of Java method mapped to Int and not platform type?

Tags: java, parameters, kotlin, fastutil

<sup>Inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625599/kotlin-what-can-i-do-when-a-java-library-has-an-overload-of-primitive-and-boxed/37625834#37625834).</sup>

In `fastutil` library there's `IntArrayList` class which has a method with the following Java signature:

```
public void push(Integer o)
```

From Kotlin it is seen as

```
push(o: Int)
```

**Is there a specific reason why it is `Int` and not platform type `Int!`?**

I expected it to be `push(o: Int!)` at least because a method with the same signature defined in Java source within the project with Kotlin sources has `Int!` as parameter type seen from Kotlin (even defined in different module, and even imported from jar of that module!).

Also, the described behavior causes `push(Integer o)` to conflict with `push(int o)` (in the same class) which has `Int` parameter legally -- they are both seen as `push(o: Int)`. If there was `Int!` for `Integer`, there would be no conflict (I tried also to define this pair of methods in my code -- still works as I expect, there's `Int!`).

---

Kotlin version is `1.0.2`.

Gradle dependency for `fastutil`:

```
compile group: 'it.unimi.dsi', name: 'fastutil', version: '7.0.12'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that it is a kotlin compiler bug.
Problem here is in interface `IntStack` which is implemented by `IntArrayList`:

```
interface Stack<T> {
    void push(T t);
}

interface IntStack extends Stack<Integer> {
    void push(int i);
}
```

Kotlin sees only one method `push(Int)` in interface `IntStack`, or, more precisely, kotlin wrongly supposes that `push(int i)` is an override of method `push(T t)`.