# How to fix Overload Resolution Ambiguity in Kotlin (no lambda)?

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

I am having Overload Resolution Ambiguity error in this line:

`departureHourChoice!!.selectionModel.select(currentHourIndex)`

For Reference:

- `departureHourChoice` is a `ChoiceBox<Int>`, which is from `java.scene.control`
- `currentHourIndex` is an `Int`
- The Overload Resolution Ambiguity happens in the `.select()` method; It is overloaded and can accept two kinds of parameters: `(T obj)` or `(int index)`.
- The `.select()` method allows for an item in a `ChoiceBox` to be selected, and you can determine which one can be selected by referencing to that item or to it's index. In this case, I want it to be selected by Index (`int`).
- Here is a photo of the error[image]

How would one resolve the Overload Resolution Ambiguity?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that you are hit by [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11440) as a workaround you can :

- box the `currentHourIndex`:

  ```
  lateinit var departureHourChoice: ChoiceBox<Int>
  ...
  val currentHourIndex = 1
  departureHourChoice.selectionModel.select(currentHourIndex as Int?)
  ```
- or change declaration of `ChoiceBox` to use `java.lang.Integer` instead of Kotlin's `Int`:

  ```
  lateinit var departureHourChoice: ChoiceBox<java.lang.Integer>
  ...
  val currentHourIndex = 1
  departureHourChoice.selectionModel.select(currentHourIndex)
  ```

Further reading:

- [Why is Integer parameter of Java method mapped to Int and not platform type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625983/why-is-integer-parameter-of-java-method-mapped-to-int-and-not-platform-type)
- [Kotlin: What can I do when a Java library has an overload of both primitive and boxed type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625599/kotlin-what-can-i-do-when-a-java-library-has-an-overload-of-both-primitive-and/37625834#37625834)

Answer (score 3):

Try casting to `Int`:

```
departureHourChoice!!.selectionModel.select(currentHourIndex as Int)
```

Comment: this does not compile either since `currentHourIndex` is already an `Int`

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me in similar situation is to define in your import for example:
import kotlin.math.sqrt as kotsqrt

then use as:
val a = kotsqrt(2.3)