# Overload resolution ambiguity HashMap.get kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I just updated the Android Q SDK to revision 2 in android studio and now I get an error with getting values from a hashmap

[image]

`it` is `HashMap<String,String>` and this code was fine until I did the update in android studio to Q revision 2.

This is where my HashMap comes from

```
val map = HashMap<String,String>()
map["owner"] = shipment.owner
map["current"] = signedInUser
shipmentOwnedLiveData.postValue(map)
```

I found a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779666/how-to-fix-overload-resolution-ambiguity-in-kotlin-no-lambda) but non-android related and its a few years old

Anyone know what the issue is or how to fix it?

**Edit:**

Seems like it also broke ArrayLists too as calling `.contains` or `.remove` on a collection also throws an ambiguity error.

it looks like there are duplicate methods for all of these

**Edit 2:**

Looks like I am not the only person with this issue

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139041608#comment3

Comment: maybe remove the double bang ?

Comment: tried that, made no difference. That was me just trying things anyway

Comment: if `HashMap<String,String>` is your value, shouldn't both be using a double bang ? i'm entirely guessing here, i have no clue sadly

Comment: Yes but the `!!` was me trying to see if that fixed the error, I shouldnt even need it but the error looked like it was saying it was `String?` when its not

Comment: it looks like it's not picking up that your `it` is a hashmap, or there's a different way of getting values from it now, have you tried just calling in `it.get` and passing a key instead?

Comment: yup tried that too, same error

Comment: very interesting, will definitely upvote, hope you find an answer !

Comment: hmm however `it.getValue("key")` seems to be ok

Comment: @tyczj pls show how you instantiate the map

Comment: @WilliMentzel added, also looks like other people are having this issue, I linked a bug report

Comment: I posted an answer with a workaround that downgrades your Android SDK android-29 package back to revision 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403743/204480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139041608#comment14) in the issue tracker, google has reverted `r2` back to `r1`

> API 29 r2 has been rolled back from Studio SDK Manager for now until
>   the root cause is identified and fixed.

So just uninstall/reinstall Q from the adk manager and you should be back on r1

Answer (score 7):

It was a bug with the latest Android SDK 29 release until Google rolled back the update. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139041608.

If you were unfortunate enough to install `platforms;android-29` revision 2 before they rolled it back, you'll have to downgrade back to revision 1. You can do this by first uninstalling the package using the `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager` tool.

```
sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-29"
```

Then remove revision 2 from the cache by removing the `"platforms;android-29"` element containing `<major>2</major>` from `$HOME/.android/cache/sdkbin-1_b735609c-repository2-1_xml`:

```
<remotePackage path="platforms;android-29">
  <!--Generated from bid:5747142, branch:qt-release-->
  <type-details xsi:type="sdk:platformDetailsType">
    <api-level>29</api-level>
    <codename></codename>
    <layoutlib api="15"/>
  </type-details>
  <revision>
    <major>2</major>
  </revision>
  <display-name>Android SDK Platform 29</display-name>
  <uses-license ref="android-sdk-license"/>
  <channelRef ref="channel-0"/>
  <archives>
    <archive>
      <!--Built on: Tue Jul 23 11:56:59 2019.-->
      <complete>
        <size>78259143</size>
        <checksum>c8b1361cc03309a8113de92f93471524fa0c36f7</checksum>
        <url>platform-29_r02.zip</url>
      </complete>
    </archive>
  </archives>
</remotePackage>
```

Keep the other `"platforms;android-29"` element with `<major>1</major>` and then re-install the package:

```
sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-29"
```

Comment: No need to downgrade the SDK version, as another workaround we can use : 

val map: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap() // instead of val map = HashMap<String, String>()
val list: MutableList<String> = ArrayList() // instead of val list = ArrayList<String, String>()

Comment: That's not going to work for those of us with apps that have more than a few files.

Comment: java.util.ArrayList & java.util.HashMap are mutable, this will not change anything, and i think it's better to use kotlin collections

Comment: my app project have more than 400 files/classes. You can change to kotlin collections by using find&replace with regex pattern to change everything about that. You should try it :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and found a workaround for HashMap and ArrayList:
You can instantiate the map as

```
val map: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
```

For ArrayList

```
val list: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem, For now as a workaround I am using the Kotlin extension function getOrElse, which allows you to provide a default value if the map does not contain the given key.