# How to solve overload resolution ambiguity for calling generic overloaded Java class from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, ambiguity

I try to call a custom Java collection from Kotlin, which implements an `add(long value)` method in this way:

```
public class SomeSet<T> {

    public void add(int value) {  }

    public void add(long value) {  }

    public void add(T value) {   }
}
```

In Java we can call the overloaded method without any problems:

```
SomeSet<Long> set = new SomeSet<Long>();
set.add(1);
set.add(1L);
```

But in Kotlin it seems to be impossible:

```kotlin
val set = SomeSet<Long>()
set.add(1 as Int)
set.add(1L) // ⚡ Overload resolution ambiguity
set.add(1L as Long) // ⚡ Overload resolution ambiguity
```

Complete compile error:

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
public open fun add(value: Long): Unit defined in de.itscope.platform.producttracking.test.SomeSet
public open fun add(value: Long!): Unit defined in de.itscope.platform.producttracking.test.SomeSe
```

I already checked out suggests, for a very likely problem:
[Kotlin: What can I do when a Java library has an overload of both primitive and boxed type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625599/kotlin-what-can-i-do-when-a-java-library-has-an-overload-of-both-primitive-and/37625834#37625834)
But this doesn't helps here, whit this generic overloading.

> ℹ This is not academic example. It's the way the
> `com.google.zetasketch.HyperLogLogPlusPlus` class is implemented. A [HyperLogLog++](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/fr//pubs/archive/40671.pdf) implementation from google out of the [ZetaSketch](https://github.com/google/zetasketch) library.

Answer (score 1):

> In Java we can call the overloaded method without any problems:

But this is only true because `Long` has different meaning in Java and in Kotlin. In Java it's `java.lang.Long` and `SomeSet<Long>` has methods `add(long value)` and `add(java.lang.Long value)`. No conflict! Whereas Kotlin's `kotlin.Long` is closer to Java's `long` and so `SomeSet<kotlin.Long>` has two methods taking a `kotlin.Long`. So the equivalent of your working Java example is

```
val set = SomeSet<java.lang.Long>()
// if you want to call add(long)
set.add(1L)
// if you want to call add(T)
set.add(1L as java.lang.Long)  // or java.lang.Long(1L)
```

Kotlin will warn you that normally `java.lang.Long` should not be used in Kotlin, but in this case I think it's all right.

As an alternative, you don't necessarily need to change the type of `set` variable itself, just cast it when you want to call that method:

```
val s = SomeSet<Long>()
// if you want to call add(long)
(s as SomeSet<*>).add(1L)
// if you want to call add(T)
(s as SomeSet<Any>).add(1L as Any)
```

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/JI4IM5Obk) (I haven't tested with a `SomeSet` actually defined in Java, but I don't expect the Kotlin equivalent to behave differently).

Answer (score 0):

The only hack I found to to call the `add` function is, to set `Any` as generic type:

```kotlin
val set: SomeSet<*> = SomeSet<Any>()
set.add(1)
set.add(1L)
```